# How to send secure email through Send Grid?

Tags: c#, azure, sendmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am sending Email with the help of SendGrid. Below is the code for that.

```
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            EmailAddress from = new 
            EmailAddress("a.b@mycompany.com", "Ashutosh");
            List<EmailAddress> tos = new List<EmailAddress>
            {
                new EmailAddress("a.b@mycompany.com", 
                                 "Ashutosh"),
            };

            StringBuilder emailBodyContent = new StringBuilder();
            var textContent = "Hi, ";
            emailBodyContent.AppendFormat("<p>Hi, </p>");
            emailBodyContent.AppendFormat("<p>This is your email.</p>");




            var emailSubject = "Attachment names are not unique";

            msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, 
            tos, emailSubject, textContent, emailBodyContent.ToString());
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Now I want to send Secure Email. I go through the below link

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html

But I have not understood how to set port 587 through code or enable secure email setting for send grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [SendGrid v3 API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) you need not worry about SMTP at all. You simply call a web API to send e-mail. All calls are HTTPS.

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/src/SendGrid/SendGridClient.cs#L115-L120), note the *http**s***.

```
private void InitiateClient(string apiKey, string host, ...)
{
    ...
    var baseAddress = host ?? "https://api.sendgrid.com";
    ...
```

Comment: So by default send grid is using https protocol

Answer (score 1):

I also found below url which says that by default SendGrid uses TLS.

https://sendgrid.com/blog/sendgrid-and-the-future-of-email-security/